# Sinon stub not working when trying to mock out an instance of an object

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon, karma-mocha

I am trying to mock out every instance that is created with the **new** keyword for an object.

Here is the Object I am trying to mock out:

```
var SharedWhiteboardView = function(moduleEl, domService) {
'use strict';

var self;
var sharedWhiteboardProblemImage;
var whiteboardController;
var caller = false;
var toolbarController;

return {
    initWhiteboard : function()
    {
        self = this;
        sharedWhiteboardProblemImage = domService.find(moduleEl, '#sharedWhiteboardModule-sharedWhiteboardProblemImage');

        var toolbarEL = $('#sharedWhiteboard-toolbar');
        toolbarController = new ToolbarController(WhiteboardConstants.SHARED_WHITEBOARD_ID, toolbarEL, null);
        toolbarController.init(false);
        whiteboardController = toolbarController.getWhiteboardController();
    },

    enableWhiteboardEdition : function(enabled)
    {
        if(self.getWhiteboardObject() && self.getWhiteboardObject.hasOwnProperty('enableEdition')) self.getWhiteboardObject().enableEdition(enabled);
        whiteboardController.setEnabled(enabled);
    }
  };
}
```

This is the file which I am trying to test and it creates a new instance of the above object

```
Box.Application.addModule('SharedWhiteboardModule', function(context) {
'use strict';

var self;
var moduleEl;
var domService;
var sharedWhiteboardView;
var modal;
var assignmentTimer = 3000;
var sharing = false;
var assignmentImageData = '';

return {
    /**
     * Initializes the module and caches the module element
     * @returns {void}
     */
    init: function() {
        self = this;
        domService = context.getService('DomService');
        moduleEl = context.getElement();
        sharedWhiteboardView = new SharedWhiteboardView(moduleEl, domService);
        sharedWhiteboardView.initWhiteboard();
        sharedWhiteboardView.enableWhiteboardEdition(false);
  };
}
```

I am trying to write a unit test to test that the sharedWhiteboardView.enableWhiteboardEdition method is called with 'false'

However I am failing to attach a spy or stub that method out. I have tried these solutions and they did not work

//First Attempt

```
  sinon.stub(SharedWhiteboardView, "enableWhiteboardEdition", function() {return 0})
```

// Second Attempt

```
 sinon.stub(SharedWhiteboardView.prototype, "enableWhiteboardEdition").returns(0);
```

//Third Attempt

```
sandbox.stub(SharedWhiteboardView.prototype, 'enableWhiteboardEdition', checkEnableWhiteboardEdition());
```

//Fourth Attempt Trying the answer provided by chrmod

```
it.only('when type is "SharedWhiteboardModule-setEditable" should call sharedWhiteboardView.enableWhiteboardEdition', function (done) {
  const view = SharedWhiteboardView();
  sinon.stub(view, "enableWhiteboardEdition", function() {
    console.log('Hit');
  });
  module.onmessage('SharedWhiteboardModule-setEditable', true);
  done();
});
```

No error but it does not hit the console.log, I removed the 'new' keyword as suggested

Errors that I got:

-Attempted to wrap undefined property enableWhiteboardEdition as function
-Cannot stub non-existent own property enableWhiteboardEdition

Please any help would be great. I have reached a dead end here.

Here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bgmNxx?editors=0011

All I am trying to do is to have the Fake method get hit when my module calls enableEdition

Comment: fourth attempt expose what is your setup. there is no way to stub method of existing methods created by SharedWhiteboardView factory. That is because those are methods of objects, not SharedWhiteboardView.prototype. To remove the problem, you can convert SharedWhiteboardView to constructor and describe methods on its prototype.

The other way around is to expose "instance" of SharedWhiteboardView as a property of the module: `self.sharedWhiteboardView = new SharedWhiteboardView(..` and then put a stub on that specific object with: `sinon.stub(module.sharedWhiteboardView, ...`

Comment: I tried this -- self.sharedWhiteboardView = new SharedWhiteboardView(moduleEl, domService); sharedWhiteboardView = self.sharedWhiteboardView; In my test I did sinon.stub(module.sharedWhiteboardView).returns(function(){
        console.log("Hit");
      }); Threw error saying : undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'sinon.stub(module.sharedWhiteboardView)

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VPEYKj?editors=0011 <-- Created A Codepen

Comment: you cannot use `new` with SharedWhiteboardView - it is not a constructor. that is my mistake in previous comment, I'm sorry

Comment: try this out http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wgYBgy?editors=0011

Answer (score 0):

`SharedWhiteboardView` is not a constructor, it is rather a factory function. Once called (without new) it returns new object that has `enableWhiteboardEdition` as own property.

Thus a stub has to be set on that object:

`const view = SharedWhiteboardView();
sinon.stub(view, "enableWhiteboardEdition", function() {return 0});`

Comment: Sorry but I get this error when I tried it: Object is not a constructor (evaluating 'SharedWhiteboardView()')

Comment: you get it from `new SharedWhiteboardView(..)` - try removing `new`. This function create new object by just being called.

Comment: thanks for helping me out, please see the updated question. I removed the new keyword from the SharedWhiteboardModule.js, there is no error but it does not hit my console.log

Answer (score 0):

This did it.

```js
it('when type is "SharedWhiteboardModule-setEditable" should call setEditable with appropriate callback', function (done) {
    var mockSharedWhiteboardView = {
        enableWhiteboardEdition: function() {},
        initWhiteboard: function() {},
        initScrollBar: function() {},
        refreshScrollBar: function() {},
        isMainWhiteboardAvailable: function() {}
    };
    sandbox.spy(mockSharedWhiteboardView, 'enableWhiteboardEdition');

    var tempGlobals = {
        SharedWhiteboardView: global.SharedWhiteboardView
    };

    global.SharedWhiteboardView = function() {
        return mockSharedWhiteboardView;
    };

    module = Box.Application.getModuleForTest('SharedWhiteboardModule', contextFake);
    module.init();

    var shouldEnable = true;
    module.onmessage('SharedWhiteboardModule-setEditable', shouldEnable);
    assert(mockSharedWhiteboardView.enableWhiteboardEdition.calledWithExactly(shouldEnable),
           'should enable the whiteboard');

    shouldEnable = false;
    module.onmessage('SharedWhiteboardModule-setEditable', shouldEnable);
    assert(mockSharedWhiteboardView.enableWhiteboardEdition.calledWithExactly(shouldEnable),
           'should not enable the whiteboard');

    // cleanup
    global.SharedWhiteboardView = tempGlobals.SharedWhiteboardView;

    done();
});
```